# Babel typescript unexpected token '?' in statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Babel can't transform '?' in statement in typescript.

```
let t= getObject()?.fieldName;//Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Unexpected token


let t= getObject() && getObejct().fieldName;
```

Comment: https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/11/05/7.7.0

Comment: What Babel package are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use [optional-chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

add this in your babel file

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

Comment: `@babel/preset-env` will also include this